# Possible to hide a method in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, split

Last night, at some unpleasant hour, we celebrated our fifth instance of tracking down a bug due to the behavior of `String.split`, e.g. in

```
output split '\n' map processRow
```

The problem is that if `output` is empty, `split` will give you one row, the empty string, which `processRow` probably won't like.

It's easy enough to augment `String` with a `split0` method (we have), which returns the empty Array if the string is empty, but we keep forgetting that `split` has this behavior, that it is not the correct inverse of `mkString`.  Soooo, five bites from this dog are enough -- we'd like to hide `split` and force ourselves to choose between `split0` and `split1`.  Is that possible in Scala?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: Perhaps `processRow` should accept a parameter that's not `String`, and have your `split0` and `split1` methods return that type instead of `Array[String]`.  That would be one way to force yourself not to use it.

Comment: The other short answer is, use `"".lines` to split on line endings.

Comment: I appreciate all of the suggestions.  To be clear, this was just one example of how split has bitten us.  I wasn't looking for a way to fix the bug; changing split to split0 fixes it.  I'm looking for a way to cover the hole so we don't fall in it again.

Comment: There are style checkers, too, that will quarantine API.

Comment: @som-snytt: Can you elaborate?  I just checked the rules in Scalastyle and didn't see such a capability.  Perhaps I missed it, or perhaps you had another tool in mind?  If you make an answer of this, I'll make it the accepted answer.

Comment: The java tool from years ago still only quarantines at the class level, with method quarantine a future feature. I'll update if I see that feature somewhere in OSS.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that `processRow` won't like an empty string, you could just do this.

```
output split '\n' filter(_.nonEmpty) map processRow
```

You also have other handy functions hanging out in `scala.collection.immutable.StringLike`, such as `StringLike.stripLineEnd`, although this only strips the trailing line end character.