# abandon calling `get` on Option and generate compile error

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I want to generate compile time error when calling `.get` on any `Option` value, how to go about doing this?

Haven't written any custom macros but guess it's about time for it? Any pointers?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055406/possible-to-hide-a-method-in-scala ?

Comment: You have any sample code to illustrate your problem ?

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate, the questions are similar but there is a Solution to this one that can not easyly be adaped to the other.

Comment: @bmaderbacher, if there's a solution, give it. I don't see how this differs from the suggested duplicate

Comment: @Paul I've added my answer. The suggested duplicate could only be solved by writing custom linter rules, in my opinion this is significantly different form simply using a set of predefined rules.

Comment: OK, that's good. I think you could usefully answer the other question too, even if you as you say custom rules are required

Comment: @Paul I haven't tried to write my own rules yet, but if I've time to do so I may answer the other question too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a compiler plugin called wartremover, that provides what you want.
https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover

It has error messages and warning for some scala functions, that should be avoided for safety.

This is the description of the OptionPartial wart from the github readme page:

> `scala.Option` has a `get` method which will throw if the value is
>   `None`. The program should be refactored to use `scala.Option#fold` to
>   explicitly handle both the `Some` and `None` cases.

#### compiler plugin

To add wartremover, as a plugin, to scalac, you need to add this to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

addSbtPlugin("org.brianmckenna" % "sbt-wartremover" % "0.11")
```

And activate it in your `build.sbt`:

```
wartremoverErrors ++= Warts.unsafe
```

#### macro

https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover/blob/master/OTHER-WAYS.md descripes other ways how you can use the plugin, one of them is using it as a macro, as mentioned in the question.

Add wart remover as library to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

libraryDependencies += "org.brianmckenna" %% "wartremover" % "0.11"
```

You can make any wart into a macro, like so:

```
scala> import language.experimental.macros
import language.experimental.macros

scala> import org.brianmckenna.wartremover.warts.Unsafe
import org.brianmckenna.wartremover.warts.Unsafe

scala> def safe(expr: Any):Any = macro Unsafe.asMacro
safe: (expr: Any)Any

scala> safe { 1.some.get  }
<console>:10: error: Option#get is disabled - use Option#fold instead
              safe { 1.some.get  }
```

The example is adapted from the wartremover github page.

Answer (score 3):

Not strictly an answer to your question, but you might prefer to use Scalaz's `Maybe` type, which avoids this problem by not having a `.get` method.

Comment: +1 The problem with the current state of `Maybe` is that there are many standard functions, even in scalaz, that only support Option.